# cellForRowAtIndexPath: returns nil for a generic prototype cell

Tags: xcode4, uitableview, storyboard, automatic-ref-counting

This is driving me nuts!

I have a generic UITableViewController class with a generic prototype cell, with an identifier "myCell". Developing under ARC, iOS5 and using Storyboard, I am using the following method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell"];
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Title";
    return cell;
}
```

Everything is hooked up in the storyboard, file owner, etc. I have several other UITableViewController in my project, using the same concept. All are working.
This particular class of UITableViewController doesn't want to work! keep throwing me the exception:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'
```

Nslog'ed --> [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell"] = (null)

Any idea and help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

For simplicity:
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}

Things that I have already done:
1. delete and create and set up the UITableViewController in storyboard!
2. Restarted Xcode
3. Restarted simulator
4. Restarted computer!!!!
5. Deleted and built the app over and over!
None worked.

By the way, I tried

```
if (cell == nil)
 cell = [UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle....
```

.. and it will solve the problem, but again... this is ARC, storyboard, ... I am not supposed to do that. Xcode is supposed to take care of it!

Comment: I am having the same problem. Can you please tell how did you solve this issue? I must miss something in the storyboard configuration.

Comment: haven't figured it out yet. If I find the answer, I'll post it here.

Comment: Looks like we are missing something in the storyboard. It probably has some default behavior that we need to change. I wonder how many other people has the same problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually I found the bug. I can't say I found the root cause, but investigating line by line, this is what I found and worked for me.

I have some objects in my `UITableViewController` that need to be alloc/init'ed before the view gets loaded, so that when callers can set them to pre-determind values. Since `viewDidLoad` is too late, I put them in `initWithCoder` method.

Commeting out and re-writing the `initwithCoder` method solved the problem. It seemed to me, that `initWithCoder` method was initing the `UITableViewController` as some different!

Answer (score 2):

You have to create your cell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"myCell"] autorelease];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = @"Title";
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: this is under ARC, no need to alloc/init/autorelease. the storyboard is supposed to do that, as it is doing in all other my UITableViewController instances.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and just managed to overcome it.
If you are creating cells data dynamically you have to do the following things:

1. Select the table view.
2. Then go to the object inspector to the third tab from the right.
3. The first option is named: "Content". Change the selection from "Static Cells" to "Dynamic Prototypes".
4. Make sure you set the identifier of the cell properly and it is the same name you use on the "dequeueResableCellWithIdentifier"

It worked for me. I stopped getting "nil" cell values and everything seems to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

if the "IF" statement is falling to true (cell == nil) for the following:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"myCell"] autorelease];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Title";
    return cell;
}
```

then the name `@"myCell"` was either misspelled (Doesn't match) or is missing from the storyboard identifier field for the cell.